# A power series of $2\times2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
A=
  $\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\        1 & 0\      \end{bmatrix}$, $I$ is the identity matrix, what is $I+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}A^n$?

Comment: Hint: Compute a few powers of $A$ by hand, and see what kind of terms show up in various matrix entries. You should be able to recognize the resulting Taylor series.

Comment: I replaced your title with a more "searchable variant". You did well in having the full version in the question body. Excessive TeXing in the title is somewhat frowned upon here. In addition to not being searchable the resulting bloated stuff takes a lot of space on the main views. If a part of the TeX-snippet is cut off, then many things break down. I couldn't think of a more descriptive title. Change it if you don't like it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another hint:

Let $x(t) = \sum_k {(At)^k \over k!}$.

Let $U = { 1\over \sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, and note that $U A U^T = \tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$, and
so $Ux(t)U^T = \sum_k {(\tilde{A}t)^k \over k!} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_k {t^k \over k!} & 0 \\ 0 & \sum_k {(-t)^k \over k!} \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If n is even,

$$ A^n = I.$$

If n is odd,

$$ A^n = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

So we have $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{bmatrix}  \frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} & 0 \\ 0 &\frac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!} \end{bmatrix} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \\  \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

You might also be interested in looking at some hyperbolic trigonometric series.